# How to show the path of a style sheet in google chrome's developer tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome, path, google-chrome-devtools

In firebug if I mouseover a style sheet I can see all the path leading to the file, but in chrome it only shows the first 40 characters and ...

Is there a way to get the full path?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the "Network" tab and refresh the screen. It will show all of the loaded resources. In the left-hand column there is a link for each. If you mouseover the link, it will show you the complete URL.

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click and press `Open link in new tab` or `Copy link address`.

You can also use the **Network** tab, which gives you a lot more information about the request.